# comparing infinity with a number javascript

Tags: javascript, infinity

Hey guys got this weird result while comparing a number with the infinity property in javascript :

```js
console.log( 6 >= !!Infinity)
```

This gives me "true" as a result.

Can someone please explain this result to me ?

Comment: Your code gives me `Uncaught ReferenceError: infinity is not defined @ JS line 1` as a result

Comment: the constant is `Infinity` - capital `i`

Comment: `!!Infinity` evaluates to `true`

Comment: i'm running code snippet and i get true as result

Comment: Why are you coercing infinity into a boolean?

Comment: @medfouedslama What were you expecting to get as a result?

Comment: Property Infinity is a numeric value representing infinity, its value is Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY. This behaves slightly differently than mathematical infinity.

Answer (score 3):

`!!Infinity` becomes `true`.
When compared to a number, `true` becomes `1`.
`6 >= 1` is `true`.

---

When you use `!!`, you are "converting" a value to a boolean.  This is done by inverting it, then inverting it back.

In JavaScript, all values are "truthy" except for `false`, `0`, `-0`, `0n`, `""`, `null`, `undefined`, and `NaN`.

So, `!Infinity` is `false` and `!!Infinity` is `true`.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy

---

As for why `true` is treated as `1` in the `>=` operator, it's because the first operand is a number, so `true` needs to be converted to a `number` too.

Here is what the docs say about converting things to numbers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus